# VB.Net - Call a Sub with events

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to Call a Sub with events?

I have the following sub, and when I press a button, I will trigger a Msgbox.

```
Public Class SelectLevel

    Public Shared Sub Button_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Start.Click
        MsgBox("Test")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can I Call this sub in another Class? Something along the lines of:

```
Public Class TestClass

    Private Sub Testing
        Call Button_Start_Click ' I tried this first, but it didn't work.
        Call SelectLevel.Button_Start_Click ' I tried this aswell but didn't work.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thank you!

Comment: No, because you dont have specified the arguments of these event handler. But why you want to call events which are triggered if something happens? If you want to call the same function that is triggered when the user hits the start-button implement a method `Start` and call that from the event handler and also from wherever you want(from the other class). But of course you need an instance of `SelectLevel` if it's not `Shared`. Event handler should not be `Shared`.

Comment: @MatSnow: [Making events static is a great way to shoot the foot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952690/284240)

Comment: Thank you both! I'll rewrite the code if it's bad code. I don't have to do this if the outcome is shooting myself in the foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters too.

This should work:

```
Public Class TestClass

    Private Sub Testing
        Call SelectLevel.Button_Start_Click(Nothing, System.EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct except in one place. While calling, you have to give the required parameters

Your Sub Procedure is : `Public Shared Sub Button_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Start.Click`

But you're calling as :`Call SelectLevel.Button_Start_Click` (**without any values to be sent**)

Call like this:

```
Private Sub Testing()
    SelectLevel.Button_Start_Click(Button_Start, Nothing) ' I tried this aswell but didn't work.
End Sub
```

This will do your work

Answer (score 0):

If the event you need is only click event then there is an easy way `PerformClick` function

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.PerformClick()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("pressed")
End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim hitung As Integer = 0
        Do While hitung < 10
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Halo Selamat Siang")
            hitung += 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).